# output of conv layer in AlexNet

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am looking at an implementation of AlexNet with PyTorch. According to the formula, output height = (input_height + padding_top + padding_bottom - kernel_height) / stride_height + 1. so using the formula, with input of size 224, stride = 4, padding = 1, and kernel size =11, the output should be of size 54.75. But if you run a summary of the model, you would see that the output of this first layer to be 54. Does PyTorch clip down the output size? If so, does it consistently clip down (seem like it)? I would like to understand what is going behind the scene please .

Here is the code that I refer to:

```
net = nn.Sequential(

nn.Conv2d(1, 96, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=1), nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),

nn.Conv2d(96, 256, kernel_size=5, padding=2), nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),

nn.Conv2d(256, 384, kernel_size=3, padding=1), nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv2d(384, 384, kernel_size=3, padding=1), nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1), nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2), nn.Flatten(),

nn.Linear(6400, 4096), nn.ReLU(), nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
nn.Linear(4096, 4096), nn.ReLU(), nn.Dropout(p=0.5),

nn.Linear(4096, 10))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output size is an whole number of course! It's just that your formula is not correct, the expression is `height = floor((input_height + padding_top + padding_bottom - kernel_height) / stride_height + 1)`. This wouldn't make any sense otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's clipped down when you have length of output by decimal point.

Because when you look at the output variable, it'd be a matrix. Every element in a matrix worth a length, and there is no guarantee an element for 0.75 length, so it's either being clipped down to 54 or rounded up to 55. And because the kernel have to stop striding at where the next stride don't match the kernel size(you may draw to understand how funny it would be if the kernel didn't stop there), it has to be clipped down.